# Configuration in Resilience4J CircuitBreaker not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, resilience4j, spring-cloud-circuitbreaker

I'm using a circuit breaker of Resilience4J and I need to ignore some custom exceptions so I need to change the default configuration. I'm working with microservices so I have a microservice connected to a database which have some basic requests like get by id and I also have an edge service which use these requests. I need, for example, if the id doesn't exist, the microservice throws a custom exception and the circuitbreaker doesn't open in this case.

Microservice with the database:

- Get request

```
@GetMapping("/sales-rep/{id}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public SalesRepDTO getSalesRep(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return salesRepService.getSalesRep(id);
}
```

- Service

  public SalesRepDTO getSalesRep(Integer id) {

  ```
   if(salesRepRepository.existsById(id)) {

       SalesRep salesRep = salesRepRepository.findById(id).get();

       return new SalesRepDTO(salesRep.getId(), salesRep.getName());

   } else {
       throw new SalesRepNotFoundException("Sales rep not found");
   }
  ```

  }

Edge service:

- Service

```
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.client.AccountClient;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.client.LeadClient;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.client.SalesRepClient;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.controller.dtos.*;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.controller.dtos.report.OpportunityBySalesRepDTO;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.controller.dtos.report.ReportDTO;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.service.exceptions.SalesRepNotFoundException;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.controller.dtos.report.*;
    import com.ironhack.manageAllservice.service.interfaces.IManageAllService;
    import io.github.resilience4j.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerConfig;
    import io.github.resilience4j.timelimiter.TimeLimiterConfig;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;
    import org.springframework.cloud.circuitbreaker.resilience4j.Resilience4JConfigBuilder;
    import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreaker;
    import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.CircuitBreakerFactory;
    import org.springframework.cloud.client.circuitbreaker.Customizer;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;

    import java.time.Duration;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    
    @Service
    public class ManageAllService implements IManageAllService {


    @Autowired
    private CircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;

    @Bean
    public Customizer<Resilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory> globalCustomConfiguration() {

        CircuitBreakerConfig circuitBreakerConfig = CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .failureRateThreshold(50)
                .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .slidingWindowSize(2)
                .ignoreExceptions(SalesRepNotFoundException.class)
                .build();
        TimeLimiterConfig timeLimiterConfig = TimeLimiterConfig.custom()
                .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(4))
                .build();

        return factory -> factory.configureDefault(id -> new Resilience4JConfigBuilder(id)
                .circuitBreakerConfig(circuitBreakerConfig)
                .timeLimiterConfig(timeLimiterConfig)
                .build());
    }

    public SalesRepDTO getSalesRepById(Integer id) {

        CircuitBreaker circuitBreaker = circuitBreakerFactory.create("salesRep-service");

        SalesRepDTO salesRepDTO = circuitBreaker.run(()->salesRepClient.getSalesRep(id),
                throwable -> postSalesRepFallBack());
        return salesRepDTO;
    }
```

SalesRepNotFoundException.class is the exception I want to ignore, but the circuitbreaker isn't changing the configuration. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you have a look at our Spring Boot 2 starter: https://resilience4j.readme.io/docs/getting-started-3

Our Spring Boot starter allows you to extract the configuration into the config file and use annotations.